# Sonar (SonarQube) + scmstats scmactivity - no host passed in

Tags: svn, sonarqube

For some reason the SCMStats plugin has stopped working and I can't work out why?

```
12:29:52.415 INFO  - Collection SCM Change log for the last 30 days
12:29:52.436 INFO  - Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /var/www/project/public/bo && svn --username david --password '*****' --no-auth-cache --non-interactive --trust-server-cert log -v -r '{2013-08-12 12:29:52 +0000}:{2013-09-12 12:29:52 +0000}' svn://
12:29:52.436 INFO  - Working directory: /var/www/project/public/bo
12:29:52.512 WARN  - Fail to retrieve SCM info. Reason: The svn command failed.
svn: Unknown hostname ''

12:29:52.513 INFO  - Collection SCM Change log for the last 365 days
12:29:52.514 INFO  - Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /var/www/bo.dhdevel-trunk.worldfirst.local/public/bo && svn --username david --password '*****' --no-auth-cache --non-interactive --trust-server-cert log -v -r '{2012-09-11 12:29:52 +0000}:{2013-09-12 12:29:52 +0000}' svn://
12:29:52.515 INFO  - Working directory: /var/www/bo.dhdevel-trunk.worldfirst.local/public/bo
12:29:52.570 WARN  - Fail to retrieve SCM info. Reason: The svn command failed.
svn: Unknown hostname ''
```

It looks like it's not passing in the SCM string, but I've specified one in both the Project settings and the sonar properties file on the box (and tried removing one or the other)

I have the SonarQube 3.7 + Plugins ( 1.5.1 & 0.3 ) running on Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS with SVN 1.6.17

As I said, this was working with the same connection string and user/password so I can't work out what's wrong?

> svn up and commands like that run fine on the box.

Thanks,

Comment: Which version of SCM Stats plugin are you using?

Comment: Indeed there's a regression bug that happens only in SVN scm. I opened a bug http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-3151 which will be fixed in the the bug-fix release 1.3.1 of the plugin in a few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now fixed as per the comments by ppapapetrou. Had an update come through via Sonar and all working again :)

Answer (score 1):

I encounter the same problem. ScmActivity plugin is configured properly (sonar.scm.url) is set.

```
[INFO] [22:16:57.031] Sensor ScmStatsSensor...
[INFO] [22:16:57.031] Collection SCM Change log for the last 0 days
[INFO] [22:16:57.109] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "svn --username becker --password ***** --no-auth-cache --non-interactive --trust-server-cert log -v svn://"
[INFO] [22:16:57.109] Working directory: C:\HUDSON\jobs\4TimeNG-Sonar\workspace\impl\mda
[WARN] [22:17:00.765] Fail to retrieve SCM info. Reason: The svn command failed.
svn: Can't connect to host '': Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden, da der Zielcomputer die Verbindung verweigerte.  

[INFO] [22:17:00.765] Sensor ScmStatsSensor done: 3734 ms
```

However the blame information is retrieved is retrieved an can be seen, but the stats are "No Data available".

But I found the following in the log:

```
[INFO] [22:16:56.984] Sensor ScmActivitySensor...
[INFO] [22:16:56.984] Trying to guess scm provider from project layout...
[INFO] [22:16:56.984] Found SCM type: svn
[INFO] [22:16:56.984] Retrieve SCM blame information with encoding windows-1252...
[WARN] [22:16:56.984] SCM Activity Plugin is configured to use more threads than actually available on this machine.
[INFO] [22:16:57.015] Retrieve SCM blame information with encoding windows-1252 done: 31 ms
[INFO] [22:16:57.015] Sensor ScmActivitySensor done: 31 ms
```

Does this mean the sonar.scm.url setting in the sonar project is ignored and the Activity Plugin can guess the right connection from the workspace and the SCM Stats Plugin can't?

Comment: Which version of SCM Stats plugin are you using?

Comment: Indeed there's a regression bug that happens only in SVN scm. I opened a bug http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-3151 which will be fixed in the the bug-fix release 1.3.1 of the plugin in a few days.

Answer (score 1):

We have encountered the same issue while testing out SonarQube 3.7. The Sonar plugin versions are:

- SCM Activity 1.5.1
- SCM Stats 0.3

  1. We are running the same project using SonarQube 3.4.1 with SCM Activity 1.5 and SCM Stats 0.2 and it is working as expected.
  2. We have a Maven multi-module project with 3 levels.
  3. As I write this I am still waiting for the Sonar Job to finish.
  4. I have similar logs as above:

SCM Activity is working as expected (no error or warning log entries):

```
[INFO] [20:43:44.631] Sensor ScmActivitySensor...
[INFO] [20:43:44.631] Trying to guess scm provider from project layout...
[INFO] [20:43:44.631] Found SCM type: svn
[INFO] [20:43:44.631] Retrieve SCM blame information with encoding windows-1252...
[INFO] [20:45:10.260] Retrieve SCM info for C:\[...] <--multiple repeated lines for each class.
```

SCM Stats appears to be having issues with the SCM Host URL:

```
[INFO] [20:47:31.801] Sensor ScmStatsSensor...
[INFO] [20:47:31.801] Collection SCM Change log for the last 1 days
[INFO] [20:47:31.848] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "svn --username [...] --password ***** --no-auth-cache --non-interactive --trust-server-cert log -v -r "{2013-09-17 01:47:31 +0000}:{2013-09-19 01:47:31 +0000}" svn://"
[INFO] [20:47:31.848] Working directory: C:\[...]
[WARN] [20:47:34.640] Fail to retrieve SCM info. Reason: The svn command failed.
svn: Can't connect to host '': No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

It appears that these logs point to the missing or not respected SCM Host URL.
We have defined the following(slightly altered) values in the Top Level Parent POM:

```
<properties>
...
<sonar.scm.url>scm:svn:svn://path:port/project/trunk/folder</sonar.scm.url>
</properties>
and
<scm>
    <connection>${sonar.scm.url}</connection>
    <developerConnection>${sonar.scm.url}</developerConnection>
    <url>${sonar.scm.url}</url>
</scm>
```

- I have not taken the time to determine which SCM property should have which value so I set them all the same.
- I tried going into the individual projects to set the values, but that has no impact.
- Is it possible that there is a configuration setting not being overridden which results in this issue?
- Is it possible that the multi-module project structure is having an impact on the appropriate values being used?
- I see the following Sonar SCM Stats plugin issue ([SONARPLUGINS-2713](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-2713)), but it has been open since 0.1 and has no additional details.

Comment: Indeed there's a regression bug that happens only in SVN scm. I opened a bug http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-3151 which will be fixed in the the bug-fix release 1.3.1 of the plugin in a few days.

Comment: Thank goodness! I have been scouring the internet for a resolution to the same issue.  If we can get it tomorrow that would be great ;)

Comment: The release will take some days but in the meanwhile you can download and try the latest snapsoht https://sonarplugins.ci.cloudbees.com/job/scm-stats/lastStableBuild/org.codehaus.sonar-plugins$sonar-scm-stats-plugin/artifact/org.codehaus.sonar-plugins/sonar-scm-stats-plugin/0.3.1-SNAPSHOT/sonar-scm-stats-plugin-0.3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: we will wait for a stable release of the plugins.  We have gone through much pain in the last sonar upgrade and I need to give our team some confidence in our build process.  Thanks for providing a quick solution though.